# Scroll lag on specific location - Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, scroll, lag

You can see the issue live here: http://www.mtthwbsh.com/

I've read up on people having issues with scroll lag in Chrome, but haven't come across anything that's so specific to a single location on the page. If you scroll past the "resume" section and then back up it's extremely choppy and stalls for a significant amount of time. Wondering if this has something to do with file sizes, but it's less extreme in browsers other than Chrome.

Comment: Thanks! It's definitely a work in progress, I'm mostly working at getting all the WP functionality/structure done before I get into more styles and RWD, but it should be a little more accessible after I remove this insanely large thumbnail haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is anything to do with jQuery. It's down to the ludicrously massive 6784×6784px 1.4mb JPEG you've got in the "work" section. I guess Chrome is dropping it from memory when it goes off-screen, and then has to re-render it before you can scroll back up.

It doesn't need to be anywhere near that big, especially seeing as you're putting it into a 254px square box.

Comment: Oh, wow, that is the wrong file entirely. Thanks for bringing this to my attention, otherwise I would've kept overlooking it, that's not the web optimized file.

Comment: All is fixed, thanks for bringing me back to something I kept overlooking.